# How to use .isDisplayed() with .each() in ProtractorJS for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I am setting up a test in my Angular app to go in and click on an element and it should look to see if a certain object is displayed. This code down here I feel should work although I know isDisplayed() is meant for a single element and not multiple. I know there is a .each() function but not sure how it fits in with this. How do I use .each() with isDisplayed()?

```
it('should flip cards and check to make sure graph is visible', function(){
var cards = element.all(by.repeater('card in cards'));
var backOfCard = element.all(by.css('#current-status ul li .back canvas'));

expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8000/app/#/dashboard');
expect(cards.count()).toBe(4);
cards.click().then(function(){
    expect(backOfCard.isDisplayed()).toBe([true, true, true, true]);
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually call `isDisplayed()` on `ElementArrayFinder`:

```
expect(backOfCard.isDisplayed()).toBe([true, true, true, true]);
```

Alternatively, [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) can be used here:

```
var values = backOfCard.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
});
expect(values).toBe([true, true, true, true]);
```

---

And, you can even [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) it to have a single boolean value to check:

```
var allDisplayed = backOfCard.reduce(function (acc, elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed && acc;
    });
}, false);
expect(allDisplayed).toBeTrue();
```